# Python subprocess command to run echo and leave the window open

Tags: python, windows, command, subprocess, echo

in python 2.7, I'm trying to:

1. Ping an IP address with a subprocess command without showing a console window.
2. If the ping subproccess command returns anything other than 0, alert the user that the ping failed
3. alert the user using an echo command via a subproccess

Steps 1 and 2 are done. I am having problems with step 3. If there is a better way to do this than what I'm trying to do, I'm open to suggestions. I just wanted a quick and easy way to display a short warning to the user.

The big issue with step 3 is the console window appears, but disappears very quickly. Ideally I'd like to leave the window open until some user feedback is received, but at this point I'll take a timeout too.

Here is what I have:

`subprocess.call(['echo', 'One or more of the IPs failed to respond to their ping. Check Logs', ' & pause'])`

The end result I'm looking for is the user is going about their daily business on their PC, a popup occurs that tells them a planned ping attempt did not reach its destination, the user provides feedback to close the popup.

Comment: unrelated: you could use a GUI window to display the alert e.g., `tkMessageBox.showwarning()` instead of launching `echo` command in a new Windows console.

Comment: I did some quick research and saw that was an option, but I thought just sending out an echo command would be quick and easy since I already learned how to use the subprocess command. But maybe it wasn't easier! I'll have to look into that next time I need a window

Comment: If you don't know how to use `tkMessageBox.showwarning()`; just ask (as a separate question). I would try `import tkMessageBox; tkMessageBox.showwarning('title', 'text')` and make sure that it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a windows enviroment:

```
def cmdMessage(message):
    subprocess.call('cmd /K "echo ' + message + '"')

cmdMessage('One or more of the IPs failed to respond to their ping. Check Logs')
```

Comment: That assumes a Windows environment.

Comment: It does :/ I'll add it to my answer

Comment: This works perfectly. I was experimenting with the cmd /K option but couldn't find a working combination. This makes sense though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(['echo', 'One or more of the IPs failed to respond to their ping. Check Logs', ' & pause'])
```

The `& pause` part isn't going to work because that's something that your shell (be it Bash, Tcsh, whatever) is interpreting. This would literally send "& pause" as a second argument to the `echo` command.

Just out of curiosity, why don't you simply print your feedback in Python?

```
print "One or more of the IPs failed to respond to their ping. Check logs."
```

If you want to pause, you can use `time.sleep` from the `time` module. If you want to wait for use input, you can do that with raw_input:

```
print "One or more of the IPs failed to respond to their ping. Check logs. Hit enter to continue."
raw_input()
```

Comment: He wants it to pop a window, so the user will notice, so printing won't really help

Comment: I had a feeling the '& pause' was just being echoed out and it was wrong, but I couldn't see it! :p

Ni would be correct. The point is if everything is working correctly, The user shouldn't know anything even happened. I'm going to schedule this to run every morning to check on some PC's, but I don't really care about the result if they are all online.

Comment: The problem probably isn't the separate arguments (on Windows, they have to get smooshed back together into a single string anyway) but just the fact that `echo` is a shell command, not an executable.

Comment: At any rate, I don't know why a Python process should output via calling a shell command, or another executable. The print function/statement is clearly the way to go. ;)